# How to plot labeles inside of FL Chart with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use FL Chart with Flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

I would like to put label on inside plot.

Now the picture is left side.

[image]

Are there any good samples or documents?
Only I can find is API document. It is hard to implement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Hope I'm not too late in answering this. but whoever is looking for an answer, here is what I figured out recently:

Inside the `LineChartData`, you can customize the tooltip as what you want in **lineTouchData** properties. below is the snippet of the code I've used to custom my tooltip information in the graph.

Inside the `LineTouchData`, `touchToolTipData` to be used might differ depending on the type of chart you're plotting. In my case, Im plotting a line chart, hence the class im using is `LineTouchTootipData`. You might need to check which class suits the chart you're trying to plot.

Chart example:

[image: chart_example]

```
LineChartData(
  ...
  lineTouchData: LineTouchData(
      touchTooltipData: LineTouchTooltipData(
        getTooltipItems: (value) {
          return value
              .map((e) => LineTooltipItem(
                  "${e.y < 0 ? 'Expense:' : 'Income:'} ${e.y.toStringAsFixed(2)} \n Diff: ",
                  TextSetting.text14))
              .toList();
        },
        tooltipBgColor: AppColour.mainBlue,
      )
  ...

)
```

You can try to take a look at this sample code for a more comprehensive context of the chart.

https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/example/lib/line_chart/samples/line_chart_sample5.dart